# setting default permissions with setfacl

Tags: permissions, files, directory, acl

I am trying to set default permissions on my directory structure using `acl`. I would like to have following default permissions for directories and for files respectively:

```
drwx--x---
-rw-r-----
```

but when I set default permissions for `group` to `x` only:

```
setfacl -R -d -m g::x my_dir
```

then newly created directories have my desired permissions, but newly created files have `-rw-------` instead of `-rw-r-----`. In other words, I am trying to remove `r` permission from directories, while preserving `r` permission on files.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88206/grouprx-permission-only-in-directories-using-acl, the desired permissions are different, but I think the problem and solution are the same.

Comment: @StrongBad - which of the 3 answers offers solution to my problem?

Comment: I think the answers say you cannot do what you want perfectly and cleanly, but I would use [Gilles's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88297/22724) with inotify as a work around.

Comment: when I use `setfacl -R -d -m g::X my_dir`, i.e. substituting `X` for `x`, I see no effect. It behaves the same as `x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Linux/Solaris ACLs don't support this. You can't set different default ACLs for files and directories.

Having directories that can be traversed but whose content cannot be listed (executable but not readable) is rarely useful. The fact that is works at all is a bit of a historical accident. Yes, it can occasionally be useful — but do you really need it? (You may want to ask this as a separate question.)

If you really need directories and files with different permissions, here are a few possibilities you can consider:

- Have your application change ownership of the files that it creates instead of relying on intrinsic filesystem properties.
- Make everything private by default (`setfacl -d -m group:mygroup:X`) and use one of the suggestions in [Group+rx permission only in directories using ACL?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88206/grouprx-permission-only-in-directories-using-acl/88297#88297):

  - Expose group-public files through bind mounts rather than directly.
  - Watch the tree with inotify and run `setfacl` on new regular files.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you can't do that with neither `setfacl` nor `umask`, as they both don't seem to allow separate defaults for files and directories. [See this similar question for another options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12445527/set-different-umask-for-files-and-folders). If you want to force some application to make directories without read permission and files with, you can either modify it, or try LD_PRELOAD given only a binary file (although writing a lib for that might be a bit of an overkill).